# CSS Sub-Menus staying open when clicked.

Tags: html, css, mouseevent, submenu

I have created this CSS drop down menu. The menu works flawless as it should, my only question
is how can I get the sub menus to stay open and not instantly disappear when the mouse is removed off of them? 
My code is at this link, 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/NJ4UP/

I have tried several things but nothing is seeming to do what I want. I would prefer not to use J-Query or JavaScript, as I'm not that familiar them, but any help will be greatly appreciated!!

All I want and need is for the sub-menus to not instantly disappear if the mouse is not hovering over them. I was thinking a timeout option or something that sets it to close after a predetermined amount of time (ie 5 seconds) or another menu or link is clicked.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Sorry to be a downer, but logic and CSS don't mix. You cannot provide a timeout or check whether something else is being clicked...that's why Javascript was invented.

Comment: Thank you for the incite. How would I go about putting together  a javascript or jquery file to do this. I just don't know much about them. Thanks.

Comment: @Jacob-IT css can handle click and delayed transitions, you can even use transparent pseudos to get a bigger area responsive to mouse hover.

Comment: @GCyrillus you have a valid point. Most web programmers see this as "breaking" the HTML+CSS+JS model. It is possible to awkwardly wield the `transition` property of an element--but it would be much more efficient and "cross-browser" friendly to use Javascript.

Comment: i agree, but transition has come quiet mature in our browsers , the 2 other option i mentionned are , as well not commun, but they are an hint and can be used to test behavior before doing the javscript(s) of the page.(i am not a programmer ;)

Answer (score 1):

**In CSS** you may expand area that covers `<li>` when hovered with a pseudo element : **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wjuov/)**.

```
li:hover:before  {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.01);/* not 100% transparent, so it gets the mouse over */
}
```

---

**In CSS** you may delay transition to close your menu **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/hEJbd/)**.

1. do not use display to hide/show the submenu
2. Use a rule that handles number value.

```
#menu ul > li ul {
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:-9999px;
  transition:0s 0.5s;/* stay open 0.5sec before to hide again */
}
    #menu ul > li:hover > ul {
  margin:0;
    transition:0s 0s;/* show ! don't wait */
}
```

Comment: There is an error in your second demo. `transition:0s 0.5ss;` should be `transition:0s 0.5s;`

Comment: make a refresh it should be fixed :) or fixed it live to test. Else , you have here : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/share/zip/hEJbd/ the file zipped , so you can open them plain

Answer (score 0):

You could check this out, maybe it helps:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you may use the experimental rule `pointer-events` and HTML `tabindex` attribute .

1. `pointer-events` to control mouse events hover `<a>` in `<li>` first level.
2. `tabindex` for `<li>` first level , so it can be focused via click & tab.

The idea is:

1. to shortcut the click events on  so `<li tabindex="0">` can take the `:focus` and apply
   same rule as `:hover`.
2. then once `<li>` has focus , to give back to  ability to receive mouse events.

**[DEMO - CSS click open/close menu](http://fiddle.jshell.net/NJ4UP/2/)**

---

it alows to open close menu via the key tab

At the moment i believe it is better to set a class instead tabindex and use javasript to toggle class on click , or at least to keep the :hover rule effective.

---

It can be done somehow for a [two level menu](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/krczi) too

Comment: Thank you. This works perfect in Chrome and FF. But doesn't work in IE...I mainly need it for IE (specifically IE 8) is there a way to "force it"?

Comment: @user3033193 so here it is, third option: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wjuov/ ? use of a pseudo element that covers a bigger area underneath the li .

Comment: I didn't know about these experimental pointer-events! Thanks for posting this answer..it has given me something else to learn.